# How to test incoming responses to mocked service in SoapUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I make tests in SoupUI in groovy and I want to test incoming responses to mocked service. (Whether it received exactly 2 responses with specific data).

My idea is: It starts MockService, in loop it checks incoming responses. (I do not know realise this). After some time it will close MockService:

[image: test incoming message to mock service]

Comment: Are you doing this from SoapUI tool or from command line?

Comment: I am doing this from SoapUI tool.

Comment: Can you please check this - https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/getting-started.html and update the question if you still have issue?

Comment: I know this guide, it is guide for create and use mock service. I created mock service and when I run this, there are income some requests and mock service generate some responses. It is OK. But now I want to create test suite, where I except exactly 2 responses with specific data. I start created mock service from test, and now I need check correct data receiving...

Comment: Sorry, could not understand what exactly you doing. What is the context for the provided groovy script? show a screen shot etc.,

Comment: In "test case" I added new step "create a new groovy test step" and here I expect script, which run mock service and test incoming 2 responses. I will update my ask and I will add screenshot.

Comment: Well, the link is provided shows how to start a mock service, you do not have to use script for that.

Comment: I understand this. This is only my idea. It is possible, that it exists better solution. I want to test incoming exactly 2 messages with specific data. First step in test case is send the request, and server send OK response. Server send asynchronously 2 responses to mock service, and mock service send 2 OK responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution is very easy. In test case I can add new step "SOAP mock response" and I create response (with script) which I want.